# How to apply blur effect to background image in Blogger?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blogger

I've been trying to add blur effect to my posts but only thing that gets blurred is the main post content (pic: http://i.gyazo.com/9d94d2be5dc3f3ada982564aa212336e.jpg). Any idea how to target the background-image, instead of the content?

The code I am using at the moment is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var image = document.querySelector('.post-body img').src;
var target = document.body;
target.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + image + ")";
target.style.backgroundSize = "cover";
document.body.style["background-attachment"] = "fixed";
</script>
```

I have a odd feeling that you need to make the actual background image into standalone element but I have no idea how.

Also, is there a possibility I could add [Blur.js](http://blurjs.com/) into blogger or is it only for Wordpress? If yes, I'd like to know how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I worked on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41321500/random-background-image-on-blogger/41321989#41321989) and saw this question. So here's a suggestion.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function showBackground() {
        document.getElementsByClassName('body-fauxcolumn-outer')[0].style.backgroundImage = "url('http://backgroundImage.jpg')";
        document.getElementsByClassName('body-fauxcolumn-outer')[0].style.backgroundPosition = "center center";
        document.getElementsByClassName('body-fauxcolumn-outer')[0].style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
        document.getElementsByClassName('body-fauxcolumn-outer')[0].style.backgroundAttachment = "fixed";
        document.getElementsByClassName('body-fauxcolumn-outer')[0].style.webkitFilter = "blur(5px)";
    }

    window.onload = showBackground();


</script>
```

**Explanation**

As I used the simple template at this time, I noticed that the standard template has a class named `body-fauxcolumn-outer` which is used to set the background color.

So I adapt my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41321500/random-background-image-on-blogger/41321989#41321989) to answer this question.

I just added the following to fix the blur as you can see in the image bellow.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('body-fauxcolumn-outer')[0].style.webkitFilter = "blur(15px)";
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try use this CSS 3 tag:

```
filter: blur(5px);
```

You can see the mdn documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter

Comment: That's the one I used. It blurs the content, not background-image.

Comment: Could you change the background-image for the tag img? See my sample here in jsfiddle and check if is that what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/5ddsj2ap/

Comment: Changed it and it broke the code. Seems like it doesn't work.
The background image = post-body img. Which means, whatever picture I use in my post, it will be automatically as background. So, how can I do the blur effect automatically?

Comment: I did a test with background-image and the filter worked on background-img. Is it this? http://jsfiddle.net/5ddsj2ap/1/

Comment: Alright, I used your code but... nothing happened.

http://gyazo.com/43ffeb70b70bedccd781a0702f154b35

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on Blogger without using any JS or CSS.

1. Upload your image into a Blogger post as if you want to put it in an article.
2. Copy the URL of the image and paste it into the `body` css like so:

   ```
   body {
       background-image: url('YOUR IMAGE URL HERE');
   }
   ```
3. Replace the `/s-1600/` part of the url with `/s1600-fcrop64=1,000f0000ffceffff:Soften=1,20,0/`

Note: You can adjust the radius of the blur by fiddling with the second number after `Soften=`(in the case above, `20`).

The advantage of doing this is it's lighter on code and completely compatible with every device and browser that is capable of loading an image!

Comment: @funilrys Yes I meant the blurring not setting the background image.