# random background image on blogger

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image, blogger

I'm trying to pull together some kind of code that will randomize the background image on my blogger blog.

My programming skills are scant, but I'm willing to try suggestions out.

I remember achieving s/th similar in Wordpress, by having a file of php-code stored inside a folder of images and then calling that php file - as if it was an image - from within CSS.

But from what I read, blogger doesn't recognize php, so I guess I'll have to try out some javascript (?)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var image= new Array()
image[0]="Image01URL"
image[1]="Image02URL"
image[2]="Image03URL"
image[3]="Image04URL"
image[4]="Image05URL"
var random=Math.floor(5*Math.random());
document.write("<style>");
document.write("body {");
document.write(' background:url("' + image[random] + '") no-repeat fixed center center;');
document.write(" }");
document.write("</style>");
</script>`
```

I've tried the above but seen no results.

Besides, [the article](http://tips-for-new-bloggers.blogspot.gr/2007/05/random-header-and-background-images.html) is from 2007, and I fear the method described may be outdated.

What's more, I don't really know where to put it.

Is it at the beginning of the `<body>` tag or should it be stored somewhere as an external file? And if so, how should I reference it from inside blogger? It would be slick to reference it from within CSS, but I have no idea if this is possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how I would do it but as usually, I'm open for edit, comments, ameliorations and suggestions if there's a way to make this code - and me - a better one.

So you wasn't that far cause actually my code look a bit like yours but with the abstraction of manually add the multiplier to the random number generator. With this all you have to do is to set your backgrounds URLs under the `imageURLs` variable.

[Here's](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp) the documentation for the `.style` object.

```html
    <script type="text/javascript">
function backgrounds() {
    var imageURLs = ["https://wallpapers.wallhaven.cc/wallpapers/full/wallhaven-301322.jpg", "https://wallpapers.wallhaven.cc/wallpapers/full/wallhaven-103541.jpg", "https://wallpapers.wallhaven.cc/wallpapers/full/wallhaven-279000.jpg", "https://wallpapers.wallhaven.cc/wallpapers/full/wallhaven-106689.jpg", "https://wallpapers.wallhaven.cc/wallpapers/full/wallhaven-365847.jpg", "https://wallpapers.wallhaven.cc/wallpapers/full/wallhaven-284161.jpg"];
    return imageURLs;
}

function randomNumber(max) {
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * max));
}

function getBackground() {
    var numberOfImages = backgrounds().length,
        uniqueNumber = randomNumber(numberOfImages);
    return backgrounds()[uniqueNumber];
}

function showBackground() {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + getBackground() + "')";
    document.body.style.backgroundPosition = "center center";
    document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
    document.body.style.backgroundAttachment = "fixed";
}
window.onload = showBackground();
    </script>
```

**[UPDATE 1]**

If you have for exemple 10 pictures, then change `imageURLs` so it's should be something like

```
var imageURLs = ["http://img1.jpg","http://img2.jpg","http://img3.jpg","http://img4.jpg","http://img5.jpg","http://img6.jpg","http://img7.jpg","http://img8.jpg","http://img9.jpg","http://img10.jpg"];
```

No need to add the number 10 (in this example) anywhere cause actually the  following get it automatically:

```
var numberOfImages = backgrounds().length;
```

So in my example, the number **10** *(number of pictures I have)* which is now obtained is used to generate a random number in range `[0,max]` with `max=10` in our example. So we get the random number with the help of the function :

```
function randomNumber(max) {
  return Math.floor((Math.random() * max));
}
```

We call it under `showBackground()` with the help of:

```
uniqueNumber = randomNumber(numberOfImages);
```

Once we have `uniqueNumber`, we use it to get the url of **one** image stored under the function `backgrounds()` with :

```
return backgrounds()[uniqueNumber];
```

**[UPDATE 2]**

To continue with explanations, you have to add the script at the end of the the template HTML just before `</html>` (just tested it).

**[UPDATE 3]**

To achieve what you wanted to do with :

```
document.write("<style>");
document.write("body {");
document.write(' background:url("' + image[random] + '") no-repeat fixed center center;');
document.write(" }");
document.write("</style>");
```

we use the function `showBackground()`

And finaly to fix what you said which was:

> The background image is the very last element to be loaded upon refresh

I added the following to the script:

```
window.onload = showBackground();
```

---

**Not solved (30/12/2016 18:48 - CET)**

I currently have no mac or windows with me to test or to try to fix:

> It doesn't seem to work on Safari

but if someone want to help [here](http://stackfun.blogspot.com) is the blogger I use to test.

Comment: Thanks for replying. A few questions: Am I supposed to change anything else apart from the imageURLs? Say I got 12 images - should I fill in the number 12 somewhere? Where am I supposed to put this script? (Sorry, but I'm clueless when it comes to javascript)

Comment: @m.a.a. I updated my answer !! Don't forget to accept if it solve your problem so it can help others.

Comment: So far, no luck. I also tried adding `/*<![CDATA[*/` and `/*]]>*/` just after the opening script-tag and just before the closing one, respectively (as some suggest), but it didn't make any difference,,, Still searching...

Comment: Yup. It works at the end, just before the closing `</html>`-tag, but not elsewhere. Thanks a lot. Btw, [here](http://www.groan-zone.net/jscript/random.html)'s another suggestion. That works, too, but it tiles the images.

Comment: A little update on this one: 1. It doesn't seem to work on Safari. 2. The background image is the very last element to be loaded upon refresh, which doesn't look so good. I'd like it to load simultaneously along with the header text, for example. That said, you've still been of great help.